# Why newly created functions can not be found by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

I wonder why recently I create functions but SQL Server returns error in calling them, in a case they get added to the functions list of the database.

For example for the following function I get such a error:

```
declare @cats nvarchar(1000)
set @cats = 'a|b|c|d|e'

SELECT dbo.fncSplit(@Cats, '|')
```

Error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fncSplit", or the name is ambiguous.

Sample Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].fncSplit
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
                LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END
```

Any suggestion or solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The function you're calling (`dbo.Splitfn`) is different from the function name in your sample (`dbo.fncSplit`). Is this a typo, or might it be the source of your error?

Comment: @Ed Harper, yes that's a typo. I created another with different name and content but got the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is table-value function. The syntax is

```
declare @cats nvarchar(1000)
set @cats = 'a|b|c|d|e'

SELECT * from dbo.fncSplit(@Cats, '|')
```

Comment: That is it. *Select * from* just like for a table. I was doing select [function-name]. thanks