# How to decode encoded URL in google chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, decoding

Google chrome automatically converts unicode strings in URL to something like this;

```
?querystring=مقالات
?querystring=%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA
```

My question is how to decode the encoded text in the codes for example for a comparing purpose?

```
if (Request.Url.Query == "?querystring=مقالات")
    //do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these out :)

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("http://www.google.com/search?q=مقالات"));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.google.com/search?q=%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This one worked: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode

Comment: Make sure you accept should-be-accepted answers. I've also came across this one, which seems you should accept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897944/why-newly-created-functions-can-not-be-found-by-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for reminding that old post not accepted. In fact the 5 min delay in between the time of testing the posted reply and accepting, causes me to forget it ;)

Answer (score 1):

**URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings.**

Characters such as a question mark *(?)*, ampersand *(&)*, slash mark *(/)*, and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string.

`UrlDecode` is a convenient way to access the `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` method at run time from an ASP.NET application. Internally, `UrlDecode` uses `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to decode strings.

The following example decodes the string named EncodedString (received in a URL) into the string named DecodedString :

```
String DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
```